# запрос в таблицу где используется два разных id этой таблицы

Tags: php, mysql, sql

делаем интернет магазин, необходимо сделать вывод заказав *(таблица **orders**)*, в заказе есть продавец и покупатель их идентификаторы хранятся в одной таблице *(**user**)*, делаю запрос *(пример под вопросом)* и не чего не выводит, хотя если  делать по отдельности по каждой связки, то выводиться нормально, не подскажите как одним запросом вывести и покупателя и продавца по заказу? 
**PS:** Идентификаторы по каждой паре разные, т.е. id продавца и покупателя

SELECT * 
FROM orders, user 
WHERE user.id = client_id 
AND user.id = seller_id

Comment: Попробуйте в запросе явно указать откуда ```cliend_id, seller_id``` берёте. Например: ```orders.cliend_id``` and so on

Comment: нет, получилось(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

очевидно, `user.id` одновременно не может быть равен и `client_id` и `seller_id` до тех пор пока продавец сам у себя не купит товар.

Хоть у вас используется одна таблица `users`, но фактически вы выбираете две различных сущности, поэтому следует присоединять таблицу два раза.

Вероятно, это будет выглядеть как `from orders as o, users as cu, users as su`, но чаще все же используют синтаксис джойнов

```
SELECT  *
FROM orders AS o
INNER JOIN users as su ON su.id = seller_id
INNER JOIN users as cu ON cu.id = client_id
```

Можете также использовать подзапросы, а-ля

```
SELECT o.*
     , (select name from users where id = seller_id) as seller
     , (...) as client
```

*зы: имхо не стоит начинать изучение программирования с создания инет магазинов, а то кто-нибудь деньги потеряет в итоге.*

Comment: Всё получилось, спасибо огромное за ликбез, к сожалению sql это отдельная тема в которой тоже нужна практика. Ещё раз спасибо!